# WP Category Meta plugin fix?

Tags: categories, metabox

Does anyone know of a fix for WP Category Meta http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-meta/ or a similar solution to add images and meta data to categories? With the latest version of WP it doesn't work anymore and I really need it to work since one of my themes depends heavily on it. If there's any coder that can make it work, I might even drop some $

Comment: There is an updated and refactured version of this plugin to be found here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-taxonomy-category-and-term-fields/ Also added a WYSIWYG editor fieldtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [**`wordpress taxonomies extra fields the easy way`**](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way)

**UPDATE:**

to get the data on the front end you can use the functions that come with the class ex:

```
if (!function_exists('get_tax_meta'))
    require_once("path/to/Tax-meta-class/Tax-meta-class.php");

$saved_data = get_tax_meta($term_id,'field_id');
echo $saved_data;
```

Comment: Wow, I think this is it! However, although I could make the admin part work as a charm, I can't make the output work, no matter what. I know I'm being annoying, but is it too much to ask if you post the exact code to display the data? for example, in an archive page, I want to display the thumb for that category, what do I need to write in the code? Thankl you in advance!

Comment: @Fabio i updated my answer.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!!!! I want to vote but it doesn't allow me to, but please know I really appreciate it!

Comment: :) No problem, glad i can help.